# Cordova 4 with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, cordova

I have my cordova (4.0.0) project perfectly running on xCode and iOS but I can't make it work with android and Eclipse (luna 4.4.1).
What I did is the usual sequence of cordova CLI commands:

```
cordova platform add android
cordova build android
```

I then open Eclipse, import the project and CordovaLib from the /platforms/android folder, zipped all kind of "source attachment" from libraries and then run the project (as suggested [here][1]) but I can't run the project cause it hangs soon: The bottom bar show "Launching  99%", nothing logged on console and a final "Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded - GC overhead limit exceeded"

In the past with Cordova 3.3 and some previous version of Eclipse everything was working fine but apparently updates have messed up the whole thing...any idea or how to run a simple Cordova project with Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the VM values in **Eclipse.ini**. Set the values to 512 and 1024 as below: See [eclipse.ini](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini) for more details

```
-vmargs
//... other VM argument 
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```